# Bard library isn't seen by the vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, google-api

I'm trying to connect Google's Bard Ai to a tts but im getting this error like i don't have bard's library even tho i have it. im getting this problem import "bard.utils" could not be resolved. Is there something wrong with my vscode?

Here's the full code if you need

import pyttsx3
from bard.utils import Bard

engine = pyttsx3.init()

def get_output(prompt):
output = Bard.generate_text(prompt)

```
return output
```

def speak(text):
engine.say(text)
engine.runAndWait()

speak(get_output("Test message"))

I tried reinstalling the library, i tried restarting the vscode, my pc i even asked the Bard himself but he kept telling me to install the library that i already have installed.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the interpreter.

Comment: It's set to the virtual environment. Is that the case?

Comment: @EveMackenzie Choose the interpreter which you installed the python package in. If you installed bard in the virtual environment, you have to choose that.